# Issue retrieving friendlists from Facebook through Koala gem

Tags: facebook, sinatra, koala

I am working with a project started by someone else which interacts with Facebook through the Koala gem. For some odd reason it will allow me to create friend lists but when I retrieve them I get nothing. I can verify I have friend lists available through the Graph API by using Facebook's Graph API Explorer tool, and I do have the "manage_friendlists" permission in the application. I can also verify that it successfully adds friend lists through this application and trying to add an identically named friend list will return an error (which it should). However, when it gets to the point of actually retrieving them through the app, it simply returns the hash

```
{:me => {:id => 'my_id'}}
```

with nothing else. The method is written as

```
  def friendlists
    graph_api.get_objects('me', {fields: 'friendlists'})['me']['friendlists']['data']
  end
```

which gives an 'undefined method [] for nilClass' since there is no 'friendlists' nested hash returning. I am using Koala 1.4.0 if that makes any difference. Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am also using koala gem... you can use it as follows:

`session['fb_access_token']` is the one when user is logging in, I am assigning as follow:

```
session['fb_access_token'] = auth['credentials']['token']

def self.fetching_facebook_friends 
    @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session['fb_access_token'])
    profile = @graph.get_object("me")
    @profile_image = graph.get_picture("me")
    friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends?fields=id, name, picture.type(large)")
end
```